How to move user from one group to another with GraphQL mutation
I am using Nextjs and GraphQL API of Craft CMS. I have a subscription system in my project. I want to move users from free to subscriber group after subscription. How can I do it with GraphQL mutation. Is it possible with GraphQL?
